# bueno tengo este problema con controller __invoke

Tags: php, laravel

Esta emi controlador

with('receta', $recetas);
    }
}


esta la ruta 

Route::get('/recetas', 'RecetasController')->name('recetas'); quisiera saber cual es el error

Comment: Hola Felix Jose, bienvenido, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Y el problema es...? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando laravel 8 o una versión superior, establece la ruta de la siguiente manera

```php
Route::get('/recetas', RecetasController::class)->name('recetas');
```

No olvides importar la definición con

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\RecetasController;
```

o bien lo puedes hacerlo en la misma línea

```php
Route::get('/recetas', App\Http\Controllers\RecetasController::class)->name('recetas');
```

Te dejo el link de la documentación donde se muestra esto
[Acción única en Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#single-action-controllers)

Buena suerte!